# Are value type variables declared in local function stack-allocated?

Tags: c#

I was reading about local functions introduced recently and started to wonder about the question. Afaik local variables of value types in lambdas are allocated in the heap. Also there was something that local function have advantage over lambdas when capturing value types, which do not require in this case additional heap allocation. Still following is not clear to me:

1. Are local value type variables declared in local functions allocated on stack?
2. What about value type variables, that are declared in "parent" function and captured in local function?

(provided that parent is not anonymous itself).

edit:

```
int ParentFunction ()
{
    int parentVarLambda = 0;
    int parentVarLocal = 0;

    Func<int> lamdaFuncion = () => parentVarLambda + 1;

    int a = lamdaFuncion();
    int b = LocalFunction();

    return a + b;

    int LocalFunction()
    {
        int localFuncVar = 1;
        return parentVarLocal += localFuncVar ;
    }
}
```

where will be parentVarLambda, parentVarLocal and localFuncVar allocated?

Comment: There are two stacks.  One for local variables and one for global variables.

Comment: @jdweng: That's not true at all.

Comment: "Afaik local variables of value types in lambdas are allocated in the heap" - no, they're not. Local variables which are *captured* by lambda expressions have to be heap-allocated as they persist across multiple delegate invocations, but that's not the same as local variables *declared* in the lambda expressions. If you could give more concrete examples of what you're interested in (as code) it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: (Local functions *can* be more efficient than lambda expressions in terms of variable capture, but it depends on how they're used.)

Comment: Local function does not capture variables from "parent" method.

Comment: Note that whether the variable is a value type or not makes no difference to where the *variable* is allocated.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Yes it does.

Comment: For this kind of "I wonder how" question, little beats breaking out LINQPad and actually checking how various things get compiled. (This is no substitute for a language spec or a definitive answer that covers all cases, but far better at sating curiosity than waiting on strangers on the Internet to weigh in.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I generally agree, but that can lead to some misleading conclusions - that's what canton7 has done in their answer, but that doesn't account for all usages of the local method.

Comment: @JonSkeet It have access to them, but it need not capture them for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: and that's why I didn't suggest using this method of experimentation to actually draw conclusions and write up answers. :-) You *can*, but that requires far more care and attention.

Comment: I've never understood the fascination with the stack and the heap when you're working in a *managed* language which is meant to deal with memory *on your behalf*. Things go where they need to go based on their known lifetimes.

Comment: @PetSerAl: I suspect we mean different things by variable capture then. (I'm trying to see if there's a draft version of the spec that includes local methods so we can see how it refers to "referring to variables from the enclosing scope".)

Comment: @PetSerAl: In particular, if the local method is converted into a delegate (or if it's async or an iterator), then any local variables in the enclosing method that are referenced by that local method *are* hoisted into classes just like with anonymous functions. But it feels to me like that shouldn't decide on whether the variable is deemed to be "captured" or not.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : All runtime objects have to be allocated into a stack.  You are only looking at the middle ware and not the low level implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Added the code for example.

Comment: @jdweng, obviously the question is about where the value of the variable is stored. As there are cases such as described in the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types)

Comment: @jdweng: "All runtime objects have to be allocated into a stack" No, they really don't.

Comment: I usually just refer to any allocated data going onto a stack even if it is organized as a heap.

Comment: @jdweng: Then you should be aware that that is a) inaccurate; b) not the way anyone else uses the term, and therefore unhelpful on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : It is not wrong.  You need two allocate security regions in memory to handle both local and global memory.  It is not technically wrong to call these region stacks.  A heap is allocate in memory and just implies a larger allocation of memory.   When you allocate memory your take it from a memory region and get the start location of the region which is generally called a stack and does not necessarily imply that the region is accessed by an offset in memory.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Microsoft Terminology is often confusing and they should of learned a long time ago to hire Computer Scientist like Bell Labs then to have junior programmers design their software.

Comment: @jdweng: It's not a stack - there's no "push" and "pop" operation on the heap. That's not Microsoft terminology - it's simple computer science. (I would agree that it's not a regular computer science heap either, but the use of heap there isn't MS-specific either.) And even if this *were* technically correct in the most fiddly way, it's *obviously* not what the OP is talking about: they're talking about heap allocation vs stack allocation. Why not try to communicate with people in the terms that everyone actually uses?

Comment: A stack is an allocation of memory and does not have to implement push/pop.  In assembly language when a function call is made, an allocation of memory is made to handle local variables and that allocation is not a push/pop.  It is an offset to the stack  Then the parameter list is copied to the allocated region.  Finally an offset is made to stack so temporary memory can use push and pop to the stack.

Comment: @jdweng: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type) suggests otherwise. But given past history, I doubt that we'll get anywhere, so I'm going to stop responding at this point.

Comment: If you are passing a structure from a parent to a child by value you are not going to do 100 push/pop operations.  The compile does allocation enough memory on the stack for the structure and then does a move operation which take less instruction cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of it is heap-allocated, unless something else is going on (particularly if the compiler can't guarantee that the lifetime of variables captured by the local function don't exceed the lifetime of the parent method, e.g. if a delegate refers to the local function, or the local function contains `yield return` or `await` statements).

Let's say you have:

```
public void M(int i) {
    Inner(i + 1);

    void Inner(int x)
    {
        int j = x + i;
        Console.WriteLine(j);   
    }
}
```

Using the wonderful [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMBvIjRrMlAFgwFkAKASwDsYGHgEo6DJhICSfPol4YA1BmzCChCRPEas7abIS8BGAB7CtG+uu0b+ggFYYAvCcVC11xgEgcATi53VJnMJAF9zMMIQoA===), we can see this gets compiled to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int i;
}

public void M(int i)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = default(<>c__DisplayClass0_0);
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.i = i;
    <M>g__Inner|0_0(<>c__DisplayClass0_.i + 1, ref <>c__DisplayClass0_);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
internal static void <M>g__Inner|0_0(int x, ref <>c__DisplayClass0_0 P_1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x + P_1.i);
}
```

So the compiler's taken our inner function, and rewritten it as a static method. Parameters to the inner function remain as parameters to the static method. Things captured by the inner function end up as fields on a compiler-generated struct, which is passed by ref (to avoid copying, and so that changes made to it in the static method are reflected in the calling method).

Structs allocated in that inner function will just be allocated the same in the static method - i.e. on the stack.

---

Now let's compare that to equivalent code, but using a delegate:

```
public void M(int i) {
    Action<int> inner = x =>
    {
        int j = x + i;
        Console.WriteLine(j);   
    };

    inner(i + 1);
}
```

This [gets compiled to](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMBvIjRrMlAFgwFkAKASwDsYGHgEo6DJhJzkAPPxgA+IXz6IMAXgwAPdfPETG9QvuNLBAK3VaMAaiEEjJjAEgcATi5nhuJnv0Bfe0dfCX4VBF4bDGwvXz8iPyA===):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int i;

    internal void <M>b__0(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + i);
    }
}

public void M(int i)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.i = i;
    new Action<int>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0)(<>c__DisplayClass0_.i + 1);
}
```

Here we can see the difference. The compiler's generated a new *class*, which has fields to hold the variables captured by the delegate, and has a method on it which contains the body of our delegate. It's had to use a class, rather than a struct passed by reference.

To understand why, think about the fact that your code can pass a delegate around - it could store it in a field, or return it, or pass it to another method. In that case, it's not just being synchronously called by its parent (as a local function must be), but it has to instead carry around the variables it captured with it.

---

Note that something similar happens if we create a delegate referring to a local function:

```
public void M(int i) {
    void Inner(int x)
    {
        int j = x + i;
        Console.WriteLine(j);   
    }

    Action<int> inner = Inner;
    inner(i + 1);
}
```

This [gets compiled to the same as before](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMBvIjRrMlAFgwFkAKASwDsYGHgEo6DJhLYYAknz6JeAjAA9h4iY3qENOoUoBWGALwqMAaiEFtujAEgcATi77huJuo0BfDxJ9Mc5AA8/DAAfHryCMYycohWNvyRvOYY2K4e3oSeQA):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int i;

    internal void <M>g__Inner|0(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + i);
    }
}

public void M(int i)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.i = i;
    new Action<int>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>g__Inner|0)(<>c__DisplayClass0_.i + 1);
}
```

Here, the compiler's spotted that it needs to create the delegate anyway, so it generates the same code as in the previous example.

Note that there are other cases where the compiler has to perform heap allocations when calling a local function, such as if the local function has to be resumable because it contains `yield return` or `await` statements.

---

To address the specific example in your edit:

```
int ParentFunction ()
{
    int parentVarLambda = 0;
    int parentVarLocal = 0;

    Func<int> lamdaFuncion = () => parentVarLambda + 1;

    int a = lamdaFuncion();
    int b = LocalFunction();

    return a + b;

    int LocalFunction()
    {
        int localVar = 1;
        return parentVarLocal += localVar;
    }
}
```

We can again [put this into SharpLab, and get](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMBvIjRjASwDsYMAFCBOdlAKwxmAe1YYAFAEoGTeoSaKW7DAAcefGADUeAGQhhgAEwgYAvBjQEFSxmw7re7HQl0iAxhAA25y9dm2ggA89gB8GF4GJoKi4hbS5uGOmi76hiYYANQYeEQBSvYYphaRYNECsdLWtnYqwL5unl6CwmJVeTaBAOxFWRjA/p0FKo3eLZUyQ4ryNcMcXh7eLr65UzUoPcnOeos+mSW7LtU1AL75Z4QnQA===):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int parentVarLambda;

    public int parentVarLocal;

    internal int <ParentFunction>b__0()
    {
        return parentVarLambda + 1;
    }

    internal int <ParentFunction>g__LocalFunction|1()
    {
        int num = 1;
        return parentVarLocal += num;
    }
}

private int ParentFunction()
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.parentVarLambda = 0;
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.parentVarLocal = 0;
    int num = new Func<int>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<ParentFunction>b__0)();
    int num2 = <>c__DisplayClass0_.<ParentFunction>g__LocalFunction|1();
    return num + num2;
}
```

Note that the compiler's realised that it had to create a new instance of a generated class for the delegate *anyway*, so it's just opted to deal with the local function in the same way at no extra cost. It doesn't make much difference in this case, but this technique is needed where the delegate and the local function capture the same variables - they need to be hoisted into the same generated class.

Because of this, both `parentVarLambda` and `parentVarLocal` were allocated on the same compiler-generated class, and `localFuncVar` just got optimized away (but would have been allocated on the stack in `<ParentFunction>g__LocalFunction|1()`).

Comment: Except that's not *always* the case. Try adding `Action<int> action = Inner;` as another line of your method...

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, thanks! I was going to contrast local functions with the code generated for delegates anyway, so tying the two together at the end makes sense.

Comment: This also happens in other cases where the compiler can't control the lifetime, e.g. if it's an iterator or an async method.

Comment: Yep, a comment to that effect is at the end of the 3rd section (hidden in the noise, granted). I'll repeat it at the start.